# Windows 10 Homestead / Laravel no page loading

Tags: php, windows, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm trying to get a local Laravel setup working using Homestead. I've followed the guide [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead) but after running the VM, Chrome just says "This site can’t be reached".

During `vagrant up` there are no errors, it seems to be pointing to the correct folders (If i vagrant ssh i can navigate to my project folder) so I don't know how else to debug the issue.

I'm using these versions:

`PHP 7.1.0
Vagrant 2.0.0
VirtualBox 5.1.28
Windows 10`

I've added `192.168.10.10 test.localhost` to my Hosts file.

Here is the contents of my Homestead.yaml file:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/Work/2017/LaravelProjects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: test.localhost
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

I'm at a bit of a loss now, anything that I may have missed? Not sure if it's worth mentioning but I have worked with vagrant/VirtualBox in the past for a different company and it was setup for me so maybe there's a possibility that they've changed something on my system that is interfering with it in some way.. seems unlikely though.

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: ssh into the VM and make sure you can access the site from the VM, from host can you access the site through the IP -

Comment: How do you access the site from the VM, I can ssh in and see all the files there but I don't know how to actually view the site that way?

Comment: running curl or wget can be enough just to check if you can access your site from the VM

Answer (score 0):

you added `test.localhost` but in the screen you tried to access `yopa.localhost` ? Have you tried with `test.localhost` or change it to `yopa` ? sorry if I didn't understand but just wanted to make sure that this is not the problem

Comment: Ah my bad, that's just an old screenshot, I have tried with test.localhost as well.

Comment: Oh ok, you tried to write the path with backslashes ? `D:\Work\2017\LaravelProjects` don't forget to run `vagrant reload --provision` after a modification